# Are facebook friend suggestions reflexive?

Tags: facebook

If facebook suggests that I become friends with person A, does person A have a friend suggestion that is me?

Answer (score 6):

When someone suggests a friend for you (clicks the "Suggest Friends for James" link on your profile, then yes.
For the friend suggestions that facebook puts on your homepage, probably but it depends facebook's algorithm and how you're all connected.